# BigQuery - JSONpath recursive operator (1/2)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jsonpath

Is there any way to perform a recursive search on a JSON string object in BigQuery in absence of the operator ".." which is apparently not supported ?

Motivation: access "name" without knowing "students" and "class" in the below.

**Query**

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$..name') AS first_student
FROM UNNEST([
'{"class" : {"students" : {"name" : "Jane"}}}'
]) AS json_text;
```

**Desired output**

```
+-----------------+
| first_student   |
+-----------------+
| "Jane"          |
+-----------------+
```

**Current output**

```
Unsupported operator in JSONPath: ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(json_text, r'"name" : "(\w+)"') AS first_student
FROM UNNEST([
'{"class" : {"students" : {"name" : "Jane"}}}'
]) AS json_text;
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Well done thanks - this does the trick ! Two subsidiary questions: 1) What if I want to scope only to "name" within "students", i.e. like "$..students.name" 2) Any performance loss when using REGEXP_EXTRACT vs. JSON_EXTRACT ?

Comment: i don't think there should be performance concern about regexp_... vs. json_... in any case  - it is more about which one can give you what you want

Comment: Done - Thanks for answering point 1) too if you can.

Comment: as of your first follow up question - please post new question with all related details - will be happy to answer it too. please provide relevant data sample illustrating your case!!

Comment: Posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290143/bigquery-jsonpath-recursive-operator-2-2

Comment: sure, will check shortly ... :o)