# BigQuery - JSONpath recursive operator (2/2)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jsonpath

Is there any way to realize a recursive search on a JSON string object in BigQuery in absence of the operator "..", which is apparently not supported ?

Motivation: access "name" only when located within "students" in the below.

**Query**

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$..students.name') AS first_student
FROM UNNEST([
'{"class" : {"students" : {"name" : "Jane"}}}'
]) AS json_text;
```

**Desired output**

```
+-----------------+
| first_student   |
+-----------------+
| "Jane"          |
+-----------------+
```

**Current output**

Unsupported operator in JSONPath: ..

Comment: I think you are missing important nuances that you mentioned in comments of answer on your previous question! my understanding was  - you want only name which is within "student" and not otherwise! If i am correct - please update your question respectively and provide data sample which reflects this!!

Comment: Question updated. Data sample is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to realize a recursive search on a JSON string object in BigQuery in absence of the operator "..", which is apparently not supported ?

Consider below approach

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return jsonPath(JSON.parse(json), json_path);
"""
OPTIONS (
  library="gs://some_bucket/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
SELECT CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$..students.name') AS first_student
FROM UNNEST([
'{"class" : {"students" : {"name" : "Jane"}}}'
]) AS json_text;
```

with output

[image]

Note: to overcome current BigQuery's "limitation" for JsonPath, above solution uses UDF + external library - `jsonpath-0.8.0.js` that can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads and uploaded to Google Cloud Storage - gs://some_bucket/jsonpath-0.8.0.js

Comment: Amazing - thanks Mikhail ! Any idea if the recursive path (via UDF) would be a unique feature of BigQuery compared to other cloud offerings (PostgreSQL/Redshift, Azure SQL, ..) ? I'm listing the arguments of BigQuery for my product.. Thanks !

Comment: Also in case you don't want to create a bucket you can use the online library `library="https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/jsonpath/jsonpath-0.8.0.js.txt"`